# What does the * (asterisk) next to radio and nav aid frequencies on Jeppesen charts refer to?

Tags: aeronautical-charts, instrument-procedures, jeppesen

For Bournemouth, all radio frequencies and LOC IBMH are marked with an asterisk - *

[image]

Many other airports also have these markings, such as: Southampton, Alderney, Jersey, Guernsey, Exeter...

However, Cardiff doesn’t have an asterisk preceding to its radio frequencies:

[image]

But it does have one before LOC ICWA

**What does an asterisk, preceding a frequency, refer to?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means that this frequency is not always available (not always staffed). From the [Introduction to Jeppesen Navigation Charts](https://ww2.jeppesen.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/Introduction-to-Jeppesen-Navigation-Charts.pdf):

> [image: Communication]
>
> 8 - Indicates the service is part time.

And further below:

> Navaid boxes include the navaid name, identifier, Morse code, and frequency. A letter "D" indicates
> DME capability **with an asterisk indicating part time**.

Comment: So tht would be the same for the LOC IBMH, the would turn off the ILS system?

Comment: So yes, according to Jeppesen it means exactly that: it is only available "part time".

Comment: As per UK AIP, EGHH is open 0630-2130. ATS follow AD operating hours, and IMBH is also marked as HO. EGFF on the other hand is open H24, however the ILS is still marked as HO (probably because only one ILS can be on at the time, the other will be off)

Comment: https://www.aurora.nats.co.uk/htmlAIP/Publications/2020-08-13-AIRAC/html/eAIP/EG-AD-2.EGHH-en-GB.html#EGHH-AD-2.3